# Sinon stub class and returning another

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocking, sinon, es6-class

I want to replace real class with a fake class with sinon

```
class FakeClass {
  constructor() {
    console.log('FakeClass::constructor');
    this.name = 'FakeClass';
  }

  test() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

class RealClass {
  constructor() {
    console.log('RealClass::constructor');
    this.name = 'RealClass';
  }

  test() {
    return this.name;
  }
}


const ns = {
  FakeClass,
  RealClass
}

sinon.stub(ns, 'RealClass').callsFake(FakeClass);
// sinon.stub(ns.RealClass, 'prototype').returns(FakeClass.prototype);
// sinon.stub(ns.RealClass.prototype, 'constructor').callsFake(FakeClass.prototype.constructor);

const realClass = new ns.RealClass();
console.log(realClass.test());
```

However, I tried multiple options but I don't get it to work with the fake class. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
sinon.stub(ns, 'RealClass').returns(new FakeClass()); // works!!

const realClass = new ns.RealClass();
assert.equal(ns.RealClass.calledWithNew(), true);
console.log('name', realClass.test());
```